# Bijection with continuous factors continuous on each fiber.

Tags: general-topology

Suppose $X$ , $Y$ , and $Z$ are compact metric  spaces.
Suppose $g: Y\to Z$ is a continuous surjection.
Suppose $f:X\to Y$ is a bijection such that $g\circ f:X \to Z$ is continuous and the restriction of $f$ to $f^{-1}g^{-1}(z)$ is continuous for all $z\in Z$.

Does it follow that $f$ is continuous?

Edit: As answered by Adayah the answer in general is "no".

So part 2 of the question: Does the conclusion hold with the additional assumption that each fiber $g^{-1}z$ is connected.
I asked this as a separate question here: 
[Continuity of bijection with continuous factor, continuous on each fiber, and each fiber connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389394/continuity-of-bijection-with-continuous-factor-continuous-on-each-fiber-and-ea)

Comment: Since $X$ and $Y$ are both compact and Hausdorff, can you perhaps show that preimages of closed sets are closed?

Comment: Do you mean that the restriction of $f$ to $(g\circ f)^{-1}\{z\}$ is continuous for all $z\in Z$?

Comment: John Griffin:Yes-edited to reflect this.

Comment: Randall: I see that $f^{-1}(g^{-1}A)$ is closed for every closed subset $A$ of $Z$, but not every closed subset of $Y$ has this form...

Comment: Given a closed set $C$ in $Y$, pushing it forward under $g$ produces the closed set $g(C)$ in $Z$.  Understandably, if you pull this back under $g$ you'll get $C \subseteq g^{-1}(g(C))$, something potentially larger than $C$ but still closed.  So, while not every closed set in $Y$ takes that form, they are all subsets of something of that form.  

Not claiming this helps, just spitballing.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, $(g\circ f)^{-1}(Z) = X$, so that last statement does in fact show that $f$ is continuous everywhere on $X$.

Comment: cderwin: I don't see the conclusion...for example the statement is clearly false without the assumption that $g$ is continuous.

Comment: How so?  $g^{-1}(Z) = Y$, and $f^{-1}(Y) = X$.

Comment: I mean that I don't see how to use the continuity of $f$ on each fiber to get continuity everywhere...

Comment: Something about all this compactness and continuity on fibers is just screaming out Tube Lemma to me, but I can't make it work.

Comment: Since $(g\circ f)^{-1}(Z) = X$, $f$ is locally continuous at all points in $X$.  So it is continuous everywhere.  Unless you're trying to prove that it's uniformly continuous or satisfies some holder condition that should be sufficient.

Comment: The argument doesn't make sense to me since fibers are not open...

Comment: This has nothing to do with openness.  If a function $f:X\to Y$ is continuous at all points in $x\in X$ (meaning it satisfies the $(\varepsilon, \delta)$ condition), it is continuous of all of $X$ in the open sets-sense.  In other words, local continuity on all of $X$ and global continuity are equivalent.

Comment: I am also confused.  I don't see how the codomain pulling back to the domain (something that all functions do) establishes continuity.

Comment: cderwin: The "continuity on each fiber" is with respect to the subspace topology on the fiber. I don't see why this forces the function to be locally continuous, since any neighborhood of a point contains points outside the fiber.

Comment: Ahh, my bad.  I misunderstood.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $X = Y = Z = S^1 \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ and take arbitrary $A \subseteq S^1$ such that $A = -A$. Define

$$\begin{align*} 
f(z) & = \begin{cases} -z & \text{for } z \in A \\ z & \text{for } z \notin A \end{cases} \\[1ex]
g(z) & = z^2.
\end{align*}$$

So $f$ swaps $z$ with $-z$ if $z \in A$ and  fixes it otherwise.

Then:

- $X, Y, Z$ are compact metric spaces;
- $g$ is a continuous surjection;
- $f$ is a bijection;
- $g \circ f = g$ is continuous;
- for each $w \in S^1$ the preimage $(g \circ f)^{-1}[ \{ w \} ]$ is a $2$-point space $\{ z, -z \}$ where $z^2 = w$. If $z \in A$, then $f$ swaps the two points, otherwise it fixes them. Either way, $f$ is continuous on this fiber.

But clearly $f$ does not have to be continuous if we begin with a wild set $A$.

Comment: Great answer.  And, $A$ need not be all that wild.

Comment: @Randall Yeah, I just wrote it for a better impression. :p

Comment: Thank you very much for the great answer! I would like to ask the same question under the added assumption that each fiber $g^{-1}(z)$ is connected (I think the disconnectedness of the fiber was crucial in your example).